# VB.NET Error: "Operand Missing" when using RowFilter Command

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataview, rowfilter

I am trying to filter a dataview based on two different columns: StartTime(DateTime) and EndTime(DateTime)...

Code:

```
 Dim dvLosses As New DataView(dsLossData.Tables("AllData").DefaultView.ToTable(True, New String(){"ID", "Name", "StartTime", "EndTime", "Loss"}), "", "StartTime desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)

 dvLosses.RowFilter = "Where StartTime > '" + hfFrom.Value + "' and EndTime < '" + hfTo.Value + "'"
```

> Error: Exception details: Syntax error: Missing operand after
>   'StartTime' operator.  at System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse() at
>   System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression,
>   Type type) at System.Data.DataView.set_RowFilter(String value)

Comment: Remove the WHERE text. It is implicit in the concept of RowFilter

Comment: @Steve yup that is it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RowFilter property is an expression more or less like the WHERE expression but it doesn't require the word WHERE. Just type the conditional expression

```
 dvLosses.RowFilter = "StartTime > '" + hfFrom.Value + 
                      "' and EndTime < '" + hfTo.Value + "'"
```

Instead I am more concerned on the fact that you treat two fields that appear to be a datetime as they were strings. If they are really datetime fields then you need a different syntax and quoting character

```
 dvLosses.RowFilter = "StartTime > #" + hfFrom.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + 
                      "# and EndTime < #" + hfTo.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "#"
```

(Assuming that you hfFrom.Value and hfTo.Value are DateTime variables)

You can find more info on the syntax accepted by the RowFilter property looking at the [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a DataColumn